# react native expo ,show/ hide <View> based on parent id

Tags: react-native, expo

i have a JSON that goes like this

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "WELCOME BACK",
    description: "Use Code FREEDISH & get lowest priced dishes free",
    ExpirationDate: "Decmber 31st 2022 11:59 AM",
    isValid: true,
    isDisabled: false,
    termsConditions: [
      { id: 1, name: "Offer valid on select resturants" },
      { id: 2, name: "Offer can be availed once in 2hrs " },
      { id: 3, name: "Other T& c will apply" },
    ],
  },

  {
    id: 2,
    name: "STEAL10",
    description: "Use Code FREEDISH & get lowest priced dishes free",
    ExpirationDate: "Decmber 31st 2022 11:59 AM",
    isValid: true,
    isDisabled: false,
    termsConditions: [
      { id: 1, name: "Offfer valid on select resturants" },
      { id: 2, name: "Offer can be availed once in 2hrs " },
      { id: 3, name: "Other T& c will apply" },
    ],
  },

  {
    id: 3,
    name: "DEAL10",
    description: "Use Code FREEDISH & get lowest priced dishes free",
    ExpirationDate: "Decmber 31st 2022 11:59 AM",
    isValid: true,
    isDisabled: false,
    termsConditions: [
      { id: 1, name: "Offfer valid on select resturants" },
      { id: 2, name: "Offer can be availed once in 2hrs " },
      { id: 3, name: "Other T& c will apply" },
    ],
  },
];
```

each value has a nested terms and conditions array associated with it.

So what i would like to achieve is when i click on more details the terms and conditions associated with that particular id should be displayed .i know i can do this using the key attribute but im not sure how since im new to react native ,any guidance will be helpful

This what i have so far

https://snack.expo.dev/@nick17728/show-hide-using-key-

Comment: May I know the component you are using to display the above details? Is it a FlatList or a SectionList?

Comment: Im using a FlatList ,you can check the expo snack for more details --> https://snack.expo.dev/@nick17728/show-hide-using-key-

Comment: I would suggest you to make use of solution like `SectionList` as adding FlastList inside another FlatList would cause lot of performance issues.

Comment: Please find a similar solution at this link https://codesandbox.io/s/qt6cz. This solution implements the collapsable section list as I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice you to create a specific component `Coupon` with its own `more details` state manager:

```js
const Coupons = () => {
  // ..

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={defaultVoucher}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => <Coupon item={item} key={index}} />
    />
  );
}
```

```js
const Coupon = (props) => {
  const [isInfoVisible, setIsInfoVisible] = useState(false)

  return (
    // ..
    <Text onPress={() => setIsInfoVisible(true)}>More details</Text>
    {isInfoVisible && (<TermsAndConditions termsConditions={props.termsConditions} />)}
    // ..
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi devpolo ,i didnt get you could you edit my snack if possible https://snack.expo.dev/@nick17728/show-hide-using-key-

Comment: Did you have any question about it?

Comment: @devpolo., I think the scenario is to show a list of terms and conditions instead of a card. In the link that he provided, we have FlatList inside a FlatList. When the user taps on a row, the list of terms and conditions should be visible.  Is that correct @BHL?

Comment: This is exactly what I am proposing.

Comment: Yes. May be could you add the `TermsAndConditions` component as well (which contains a list) so that he will get more clarification on this. We can implement a similar solution with the Collapsable section list (Which is recommended instead of Flaslist inside a Flatlist for better performance). I have added the solution link the question comments.

Comment: Please, I don't think the problem here is the Flatlist inside the Flatlist (We know that it will trigger a warning) but this is a out of topic answer. The question is more a `react` question rather than a `react-native` one.